# Plans / timescales for the final novel in Roger MacBride Allen's Hunted Earth trilogy?

Tags: books, hard-sci-fi

I've read [*The Ring of Charon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ring_of_Charon) and [*The Shattered Sphere*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shattered_Sphere) by [Roger MacBride Allen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_MacBride_Allen), as part of the [*Hunted Earth*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?1400) trilogy.  I've really enjoyed them and am saddened to see that the concluding book has not yet been written.

Does anyone have any information on if there are any plans / timescales that Roger has for concluding this (e.g. from interviews etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following on his [website](http://www.sff.net/people/roger.allen/), but I don't have a date to accompany this comment.  It also refers to his "latest novel, THE DEPTHS OF TIME was published at the end of February, 2000", so may not be very up to date.

> I receive many queries, asking if I
>   plan to do any further work in the
>   series of books started with THE RING
>   OF CHARON and THE SHATTERED SPHERE.
>   The answer is yes -- but not just yet.
>   I have not decide when I will write
>   the next one, but I definitely will
>   write it. I have always intended to
>   write an open-ended series of book in
>   this universe. I plan to call the next
>   one THE FALLING WORLD. I looked over
>   my notes for that book a while back,
>   and I must admit reading them made me
>   want to get started on it soon.
>   However -- I do have other books I
>   want to write as well. Sooner or
>   later, I will juggle my time enough to
>   let me make a start on THE FALLING
>   WORLD. I'll keep you posted.